# its possible use puppeter with robotjs in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker

im trying to run a puppeter code but works except the part of user intro and type inputs
how i could solve , please help me 
my code works click in upload input but fail when i use robotjs for type text for upload filename and type enter for submit upload ; how I could solve

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra') 

 const robot = require('robotjs')



const fs = require('fs')
textzzz=""
async function readLine() {

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input:process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        rl.question('Enter captcha: ', (answer) => {
          rl.close();
          resolve(answer)
        });
    })
}

  fs.writeFile('codigofinal', "", _ => console.log(''));



(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false ,  args: [      '--no-sandbox',      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',    ]   });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});





    await page.screenshot({path: 'zfinimage2.png'});









    await page.goto("https://gofile.io/?t=uploadFilesl", {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

await page.waitFor(2000);

await page.evaluate(() => {  document.querySelector("#li-uploadFiles > a").click()          })
await page.waitFor(2000);
await page.evaluate(() => {   document.querySelector("#btnChooseFiles").click()             })

await page.waitFor(4000);
robot.typeString("finimage");


robot.keyTap("enter");
    await page.screenshot({path: 'zzfinimagex.png'});
await page.waitFor(4000);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'finimage.png'});

    await page.screenshot({path: 'finimage2.png'});

await page.waitFor(20000);

         await browser.close();

})();
```

im trying to run a puppeter code but works except the part of user intro and type inputs
how i could solve , please help me

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY /hello /

RUN apt-get update &&       apt-get -y install sudo
RUN apt-get install  -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install  -y curl
RUN apt-get install  -y python
RUN apt-get install -y  libxtst-dev libpng++-dev
RUN apt-get install  -y  build-essential
RUN echo "Hello World!!" > magma
RUN curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh |  sh
RUN npm install puppeteer
RUN npm install puppeteer-extra
RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm install robotjs



RUN  apt-get install  -y  gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
RUN apt-get install  -y xvfb

COPY /tryvimeo /
RUN xvfb-run node /tryvimeo >errorslog
RUN cat /hello
RUN echo "Hello World!!">magma
```

im using xvfb-run node tyvimeo for test my nodejs code

Comment: Hi Carlos, I am working on something very similar. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Hello Carlos, I'm currently having the same problem as you got there. Did you find way to solve this?